# Are all sums includable in a criminal compensation order in principle also recoverable privately via civil claims?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, civil-law, criminal-procedure, compensation

Alice was assaulted by Bob, but suffered no injuries (thus incurred no medical expenses) or other damages or loss. She complains to police, who eventually charge Bob. Bob is convicted, and sentenced to pay a charge as well as a criminal compensation order. Such an order may account for specific (easily quantifiable) losses suffered by Alice (what are sometimes in civil law called “special damages”), but also pain and suffering, as well as injury to feelings and the like.

Are all of these sums (as well as any others that may be accounted for in the amount of a criminal compensation order) theoretically also recoverable in county court by way of a private claim, if they were not already included in any CCO,  whether or not the police and CPS had in fact opted to proceed with the matter?

Answer (score 3):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

> Are all of these sums (as well as any others that may be accounted for
> in the amount of a criminal compensation order) theoretically also
> recoverable . . .  by way of a private claim, whether or not
> the police and [prosecutors] . . . had in fact opted to proceed with the matter?

Yes.